# Relationships in different namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I'm a little stuck on how relationships are defined between models in different namespaces. I have created this example to illustrate my problem and have added comments with my requirements.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account # meaning Account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # meaning User
  has_many :campaigns # meaning campaigns
  has_one :account # meaning SomeCollection::Account
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account # meaning Account
end

class SomeCollection::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account # meaning Account
  has_many :campaigns # meaning SomeCollection::Campaign
end

class SomeCollection::Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account # meaning SomeCollection::Account
end
```

The one I am most confused about is the relationship between `Account` and `SomeCollection::Account`. I would expect to access an instance of this as such -

```
account.some_collection_account
# => <SomeCollection::Account ...>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a class name for each association and choose the association name like this:

```
has_one :some_collection_account, class_name: 'SomeCollection::Account'
```